# How to solve the choosing best secretary Problem for N=100?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The problem is described in detail [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)

But what if we limit our N to 100 candidates?

1-If we have 100 Candidates what is the probability that you hire the best one with maximum probability?

2-how to Maximize the expected rank of hired candidate?

3-Compute the probability of success of “MyStrategy”

where MyStrategy is:

Wait till $\frac{N+1}{2}$  candidate

Hire anyone with best rank so far
If no such candidate then hire the last candidate?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem

Comment: Not following.  When you say "hire anyone with best rank so far" you appear to be allowing us to hire from the pool of rejected candidates.  That is not allowed under the standard problem, and it would seem to trivialize the issue (as you could just look at all of them and pick the best).

Comment: If you meant the standard problem, then the standard solution is optimal.  The fact that $\frac {100}e$ isn't an integer means you have to test the two integers nearest it to see which is better.

Comment: @lulu I am confused as 100/e is not a probability .

Comment: @lulu i have update the question

Comment: I don't see how the edit clarifies anything.  Please study the link you attached.  It clearly explains the optimal strategy for the standard problem and provides all the information you need.  If you are changing the terms of the standard problem, you should clearly state what the new rules are.